# Find duplicate values that exist within fields in different columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have table called "lineup":

```
PK  |  masterID  | WR1 | WR2 |  WeeK |
----+------------+-----+-----+-------+
01  |  1111      |  A  |  B  |  1    |
02  |  2222      |  A  |  B  |  1    |
03  |  1111      |  C  |  A  |  2    |
04  |  1111      |  D  |  E  |  3    |
05  |  2222      |  C  |  D  |  2    |
06  |  2222      |  E  |  F  |  3    |
07  |  3333      |  A  |  B  |  1    |
08  |  3333      |  B  |  C  |  2    |
```

I need to find that:

records "01" and "03" for masterID = 1111  (duplicated = "A")
and
records "07 and "08" for masterID = 3333  (duplicated = "B")

Across WR1 and WR2

I would like to see this returned:

```
PK  |  masterID  | WR1 | WR2 |  WeeK |
----+------------+-----+-----+-------+
01  |  1111      |  A  |  B  |  1    |
03  |  1111      |  C  |  A  |  2    |
07  |  3333      |  A  |  B  |  1    |
08  |  3333      |  B  |  C  |  2    |
```

I have successfully been able to find dups within a single column with this:

```
/* Find Dup wr1's */
SELECT a.*
FROM lineup a
JOIN (SELECT masterId, wr1, COUNT(*)
      FROM lineup 
      GROUP BY masterId, wr1
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b ON a.masterId = b.masterId
                             AND a.wr1 = b.wr1
ORDER BY a.masterId;
```